# How to map Administrator claim for Sitecore Active Directory SSO?

Tags: active-directory, sitecore

I'm configuring Active Directory Login for Sitecore 9.0.0. And I have issues with IsAdministrator role. I used the following map, but it didn't work.

Any idea about how to configure it?

```
<map name="Administrator Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
  <data hint="raw:AddData">
    <source name="Administrator" />
    <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
  </data>
</map>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to map `http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin` claim in *Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config* file in the *propertyInitializer* section as follows:

```
<propertyInitializer>
    <maps>
        <map name="set IsAdministrator" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <data hint="raw:AddData">
                <source name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
                <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
            </data>
        </map>
    </maps>
</propertyInitializer>
```

Read more details [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html).